# Perform an operation over a column of a dataframe in a list (R)

Tags: r, database, list, dataframe

I am trying to perform an operation in a column of a dataframe that is inside of a list.

This is the data frame inside of my list

[image]

```
> dput(wtr_complete[[1]])
structure(list(date = c("2010-03-02T00:00:00", "2010-03-03T00:00:00", 
"2010-03-04T00:00:00", "2010-03-05T00:00:00", "2010-03-06T00:00:00", 
"2010-03-07T00:00:00", "2010-03-08T00:00:00", "2010-03-09T00:00:00", 
"2010-03-10T00:00:00", "2010-03-11T00:00:00", "2010-03-12T00:00:00", 
"2010-03-13T00:00:00", "2010-03-14T00:00:00", "2010-03-15T00:00:00", 
"2010-03-16T00:00:00", "2010-03-17T00:00:00", "2010-03-18T00:00:00", 
"2010-03-19T00:00:00", "2010-03-20T00:00:00", "2010-03-21T00:00:00", 
"2010-03-22T00:00:00", "2010-03-23T00:00:00", "2010-03-24T00:00:00", 
"2010-03-25T00:00:00", "2010-03-26T00:00:00", "2011-01-01T00:00:00", 
"2011-01-02T00:00:00", "2011-01-03T00:00:00", "2011-01-04T00:00:00", 
"2011-01-05T00:00:00", "2011-01-06T00:00:00", "2011-01-07T00:00:00", 
"2011-01-08T00:00:00", "2011-01-09T00:00:00", "2011-01-10T00:00:00", 
"2011-01-11T00:00:00", "2011-01-12T00:00:00", "2011-01-13T00:00:00", 
"2011-01-14T00:00:00", "2011-01-15T00:00:00", "2011-01-16T00:00:00", 
"2011-01-17T00:00:00", "2011-01-18T00:00:00", "2011-01-19T00:00:00", 
"2011-01-20T00:00:00", "2011-01-21T00:00:00", "2011-01-22T00:00:00", 
"2011-01-23T00:00:00", "2011-01-24T00:00:00", "2011-01-25T00:00:00", 
"2012-01-01T00:00:00", "2012-01-02T00:00:00", "2012-01-03T00:00:00", 
"2012-01-04T00:00:00", "2012-01-05T00:00:00", "2012-01-06T00:00:00", 
"2012-01-07T00:00:00", "2012-01-08T00:00:00", "2012-01-09T00:00:00", 
"2012-01-10T00:00:00", "2012-01-11T00:00:00", "2012-01-12T00:00:00", 
"2012-01-13T00:00:00", "2012-01-14T00:00:00", "2012-01-15T00:00:00", 
"2012-01-16T00:00:00", "2012-01-17T00:00:00", "2012-01-18T00:00:00", 
"2012-01-19T00:00:00", "2012-01-20T00:00:00", "2012-01-21T00:00:00", 
"2012-01-22T00:00:00", "2012-01-23T00:00:00", "2012-01-24T00:00:00", 
"2012-01-25T00:00:00", "2013-01-01T00:00:00", "2013-01-02T00:00:00", 
"2013-01-03T00:00:00", "2013-01-04T00:00:00", "2013-01-05T00:00:00", 
"2013-01-06T00:00:00", "2013-01-07T00:00:00", "2013-01-08T00:00:00", 
"2013-01-09T00:00:00", "2013-01-10T00:00:00", "2013-01-11T00:00:00", 
"2013-01-12T00:00:00", "2013-01-13T00:00:00", "2013-01-14T00:00:00", 
"2013-01-15T00:00:00", "2013-01-16T00:00:00", "2013-01-17T00:00:00", 
"2013-01-18T00:00:00", "2013-01-19T00:00:00", "2013-01-20T00:00:00", 
"2013-01-21T00:00:00", "2013-01-22T00:00:00", "2013-01-23T00:00:00", 
"2013-01-24T00:00:00", "2013-01-25T00:00:00", "2014-01-01T00:00:00", 
"2014-01-02T00:00:00", "2014-01-03T00:00:00", "2014-01-04T00:00:00", 
"2014-01-05T00:00:00", "2014-01-06T00:00:00", "2014-01-07T00:00:00", 
"2014-01-08T00:00:00", "2014-01-09T00:00:00", "2014-01-10T00:00:00", 
"2014-01-11T00:00:00", "2014-01-12T00:00:00", "2014-01-13T00:00:00", 
"2014-01-14T00:00:00", "2014-01-15T00:00:00", "2014-01-16T00:00:00", 
"2014-01-17T00:00:00", "2014-01-18T00:00:00", "2014-01-19T00:00:00", 
"2014-01-20T00:00:00", "2014-01-21T00:00:00", "2014-01-22T00:00:00", 
"2014-01-23T00:00:00", "2014-01-24T00:00:00", "2014-01-25T00:00:00"
), station = c("GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156", 
"GHCND:USW00053156", "GHCND:USW00053156"), value = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 64L, 26L, 21L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 161L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-125L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and the operation consists in to make a substring of the name in the second column of the data frame in a new column (number 4). I am using the following code:

```
wtr_complete[[1]][4] <-  substring(wtr_complete[[1]][2],7)
```

but it is not working correctly as I am getting in column 4:

[image]

Any idea on how to perform an operation over the column of the data frame in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for putting together a reproducible example. You're very close to the solution you want.

One thing to pick up when learning R is the difference between referencing the values you want to work with and referencing the thing that *contains* those values. This is one of those cases.

When you write `wtr_complete[[1]][2]`, R returns a `data.frame` with just column two included. When you use a slightly different syntax, `wtr_complete[[1]][,2]`, R returns a *character vector* with **the actual values** you want to work with. The difference is just in that comma. The comma is R's syntax for subsetting `data.frame`s and `[,2]` means: "All the values in *just* column 2".

The strange output you get is because you're passing an entire `data.frame` to `substring`, rather than just a *character vector* which is what it asks for. In turn, what `substring` does is convert your `data.frame` to a character vector before doing the substring operation. See that this produces a character vector of length **1** with all the values smushed together.

```
as.character(wtr_complete[[1]][2])
```

```
[1] "c(\"GHCND:USW00053156\", \"GHCND:USW00053156\", \"GHCND:USW00053156\", \"GHCND:USW00053156\", \"GHCND:USW00053156\", \"GHCND:USW00053156\", \"GHCND:USW00053156\", \"GHCND:USW00053156\",
```

Some pretty strange output, right?

What you want to do instead, is call `substring` with *the values*:

```
wtr_complete[[1]][4] <- substring(wtr_complete[[1]][,2], 7)
```

You should get a result like:

```
                   date           station value          V4
1   2010-03-02T00:00:00 GHCND:USW00053156     0 USW00053156
```

Note: You'll see that this gives your new column a name of "V4". An overall better way to run this operation is to give the new column a name and *also* reference column two by name, which is much safer:

```
wtr_complete[[1]]$mynewcol <- substring(wtr_complete[[1]]$station, 7)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! much appreciated the help and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
df <- wtr_complete[[1]]
df$newcol <-  substring(df$station,7)
wtr_complete[[1]] <- df
```

directly from the list

```
wtr_complete[[1]]$newcol <- substring(wtr_complete[[1]]$station,7)
```

Comment: it does not work, it does the same than my code

Comment: it works, Thank you! I thought also about the solution your propose, but I was trying to edit directly from the list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Neither `wtr_complete[[1]][2]` nor `wtr_complete[[1]][,2]` are character vectors,

You could use:

```
wtr_complete[[1]]$newcol <-  substring(wtr_complete[[1]][[2]],7)
```

Comment: Thanks, it does what I want!